# Tkinter: remove keyboard double-click prevention

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm programming a python version of Asteroids (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game)) using Tkinter.

This is the piece of code that let the ship to move ahead:

```
def move(self, sx=0, sy=0, ms=2):
    try:
        self.root.after_cancel(self.m)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    ms += 1
    if ms > 30:
        return
    self.parent.move(self.ship, sx, sy)
    self.m = self.root.after(ms, lambda sx1=sx, sy1=sy, millisec=ms: self.move(sx1, sy1, ms))
```

And here there's the actual fuction that runs when Up Arrow is pressed:

```
def avanti(self, event):
    self.s = -2.5
    x = self.s * math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * -1
    y = self.s * math.cos(math.radians(self.angle))
    self.move(x, y)
```

When you press UpArrow multiple times, the code works pretty well, the only problem is that when you hold it down, the ship moves once, then there's a small break like 0.2s long, and then it starts going ahead regularly, until you release the key. I think that the computer prevents you to double-click worngly and then, when it sees that you actually want to, it removes this prevenction.

Is there a way to remove this block since the first press?

EDIT: You can actually change the typing delay on the entire computed by going on *Keyboard -> typing delay* but what I want to do is to remove the delay **only** on the python program.

Comment: you can use `<Up>` to set variable ie. `move_up = True` and `<KeyRelease-Up>` to set `move_up = False`. And then you can use `after` to execute function which will check `move_up` and move object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<Up>` to set `move_up = True` and `<KeyRelease-Up>` to set `move_up = False` and then you can use `after` to run function which will check `move_up` and move object.

Working example - code from other question (about moving platform)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- constants ---

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600

CENTER_X = DISPLAY_WIDTH//2
CENTER_Y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT//2

# --- functions ---

# for smooth move of platform

def up_press(event):
    global platform_up
    platform_up = True

def up_release(event):
    global platform_up
    platform_up = False

def down_press(event):
    global platform_down
    platform_down = True

def down_release(event):
    global platform_down
    platform_down = False

def eventloop():

    # move platform
    if platform_up:
        # move
        canvas.move(platform, 0, -20)
        # check if not leave canvas
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(platform)
        if y1 < 0:
            # move back
            canvas.move(platform, 0, 0-y1)
    if platform_down:
        # move
        canvas.move(platform, 0, 20)
        # check if not leave canvas
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(platform)
        if y2 > DISPLAY_HEIGHT:
            # move back
            canvas.move(platform, 0, -(y2-DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

    root.after(25, eventloop)

# --- main ---

# - init -

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=DISPLAY_WIDTH, height=DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

# - objects -

platform = canvas.create_rectangle(CENTER_X-15, CENTER_Y-15, CENTER_X+15, CENTER_Y+15, fill="green")

platform_up = False
platform_down = False

root.bind('<Up>', up_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Up>', up_release)
root.bind('<Down>', down_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Down>', down_release)

# - mainloop -

root.after(25, eventloop)
root.mainloop()
```